# On click Iframe need to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-ui

When loading the page automatically iframe also loading, it must  not have to do like that
When i click button, then only iframe need to load but in iframe there is url

Can you give me example in jsfiddle, please

```
<input type="button">Load</input>

 <div class="copy">
  <iframe id="font" src="${SubscriptionUrl }" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? My best guess is, that you want to load an  iframe into the page when clicking a button (that's what your code is suggesting). Am I correct?

Comment: Have you tried changing the iFrame's src attribute (on click) instead of loading a new page?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your iframe onload and then display when clicked.

```
<button id="btnLoad" type="button">Load</button>

<div class="copy">
    <iframe style="display:none;" id="font" src="${SubscriptionUrl }" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
        const btnLoad= document.getElementById('btnLoad');

        btnLoad.addEventListener("click", function(){
             document.getElementById("font").style.display = "block";
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<a>`nchor and an `<iframe>`. **No JavaScript required**.

- Set a `[name]` attribute for `<iframe>`

  ex. `<iframe` **name="iframe0"** `src="about:blank" ...></iframe>`
- Set the `<a>`nchor `[href]` attribute to the url of intended destination.

  ex. `<a` **href="https://www.example.com"** `...>...</a>`
- Set the `<a>`nchor `[target]` attribute to the `<iframe>` `[name]` attribute.

  ex. `<a href="https://www.example.com"` **target="iframe0"**`...`>`...</a>`

### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>
<a  href="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4" target="frame0">VIDEO</a>
</button>

<figure class='box'>
  <iframe name='frame0' src="about:blank" frameborder="0"  width="480" height="270"></iframe>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Initially set one attribute to iframe .While clicking button take the attribute from the iframe and set that to iframe src.
```

Just Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rph55pq7/4/)